# How can I edit gravity forms using hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, gravity-forms-plugin

I am working on a simple email signup form and want to remove all of the bloat that gravity forms has.  I know that I can't get rid of some of the javascript, but I would like be able to have the form work with out using an ul, remove the title and description, etc.

Here is what the static html version of the email signup looks like (I am using bootstrap 3):
[image]

**How can I make my gravity form go from:**

```
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper" id="gform_wrapper_2"><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_2" action="/exrnawp/" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="gform_heading">
                            <span class="gform_description"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gform_body">
                            <ul id="gform_fields_2" class="gform_fields top_label description_below"><li id="field_2_1" class="gfield               gfield_contains_required"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_1">Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_1" id="input_2_1" type="email" value="" class="medium" placeholder="Email Newsletter"></div></li>
                            </ul></div>
        <div class="gform_footer top_label"> <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_2" class="button gform_button" value="Get Updates!" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_2&quot;]){return false;}  if( !jQuery(&quot;#gform_2&quot;)[0].checkValidity || jQuery(&quot;#gform_2&quot;)[0].checkValidity()){window[&quot;gf_submitting_2&quot;]=true;} ">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="is_submit_2" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_submit" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_unique_id" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="state_2" value="WyJhOjA6e30iLCIxNTU1YWU5Yzg1OGIxMDQ3ZGY5ZGZlZGU2MzA1ODNlMSJd">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_target_page_number_2" id="gform_target_page_number_2" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_source_page_number_2" id="gform_source_page_number_2" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="gform_field_values" value="">

        </div>
                </form>
                </div>
```

**to this:**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email Newsletter">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right"><strong>SIGN UP</strong>    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the title and description HTML should be as simple as passing "false" for the "title" and "description" attributes on the [gravityform] shortcode or their equivalent on the gravity_form() function if you are calling it manually.

If you're intending to have Gravity Forms handle processing the submission of the form, you'll need to leave most, if not all, of the hidden fields which are used to allow GF to identify that an actual Gravity form was submitted (and not some other form and any other POST request to your site).

If you're feeling frisky, you can completely rewrite the entire output of the form via the "gform_get_form_filter" hook. It's undocumented but it passes the entire form markup as a string and the $form object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I need to get a handle on gform_get_form_filter.  Have you ever successfully written your own GF this way?

Comment: I have not used it to create custom form markup. Typically, I have used it to hide the form when some condition is not met (example: http://gravitywiz.com/limit-user-to-one-submission-per-time-period/).

Comment: As far as I can see, you can't edit the HTML this way. It's true that if you add a second parameter to your gform_pre_render call you'll get the form as HTML, but I can't find a way to actually edit that before it's sent back to the browser.

Comment: gform_pre_render allows you to modify the form **object** *before* it is rendered. gform_get_form_filter allows you to modify the form **markup** *after* it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jquery, which works fine, but isn't the most efficient way.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".gform_body" ).replaceWith( "<div class='form-group'><input name='input_1' id='input_2_1' type='email' value='' class='medium form-control' placeholder='Email Newsletter'></div>" );
    $('#gform_submit_button_2').addClass('btn btn-warning pull-right');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to remove HTML output using jQuery? The only reason I can think of to remove HTML is to have less to download. But if you use jQuery then the HTML is downloaded and then removed from the DOM, so there is actually more to download and to process: the jQuery you added.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old post, but since the documentation on the matter is poor and people might end-up here looking for answers (like I did), I thought that I'd share the approach that I eventually ended-up with.

So, what I did was using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to clean-up the form from the .gform_body and .gform_footer containers, as well as the ul element. Then, things get more straightforward since you can use Gravity Forms' native filters [gform_field_container](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_container/),  [gform_field_input](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_input/) and [gform_submit_button](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_submit_button/) to modify the fields.

For a more detailed description, here is my tutorial on how to [use DOMDocument to clean-up Gravity Form's markup](https://www.gsarigiannidis.gr/custom-html-markup-with-gravity-forms/).